# How to nest various `propertize`s?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-faces

I want to do the elisp equivalent of

```
 <font color="red">normal<b>bold</b></font>
```

I've tried

```
 (propertize (concat "normal" 
               (propertize "bold" 'font-lock-face 
                                  '(:weight bold))) 
  'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red"))
```

Yet the 'red' property overwrites the 'bold' property and I end up with

```
#("normalbold" 0 6
  (font-lock-face
   (:foreground "red"))
  6 10
  (font-lock-face
   (:foreground "red")))
```

Is it doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think nesting can be done with the functions elisp provides. [The docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html) suggest propertizing each part of the string individually and then concatenating them:

"
To put different properties on various parts of a string, you can construct each part with propertize and then combine them with concat:

```
      (concat
       (propertize "foo" 'face 'italic
                   'mouse-face 'bold-italic)
       " and "
       (propertize "bar" 'face 'italic
                   'mouse-face 'bold-italic))
           ⇒ #("foo and bar"
                       0 3 (face italic mouse-face bold-italic)
                       3 8 nil
                       8 11 (face italic mouse-face bold-italic))
```

"

Which in your case would look something like:

```
(concat (propertize "normal" 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red" ))
        (propertize "bold" 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "red" :weight bold)))
```

Without knowing more about your use case I can't be sure this will work for you. If it won't, you could try using `add-text-properties` (also described in the docs), which you can use to statefully modify the text properties of a string.